# Reflexive pronoun in the passive

Tags: passive-voice

Would anybody explain how to change the following sentences into the passive?

> - He did it himself.
> - He killed himself.
> - He washed himself.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert a sentence  from active voice to passive voice, the subject becomes the [agent](https://www.ntid.rit.edu/sea/processes/passive/grammatical/agents) (**by...**) or is omitted completely, and the object becomes the [patient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) (the subject of the passive voice sentence).

The most common usages of passive voice are if

- you want to focus on the active-voice object
- you don't know who the active-voice subject is
- you don't want to say who the active-voice subject is

You use a reflexive pronoun when the subject and object are the same, so there is no point in focusing on the active-voice object, as it is the same as the active-voice subject. You do know who is the active-voice subject. The only remaining justification for using passive voice would therefore be if you did not want to say who was the active-voice subject. In this case, the second and third sentences become:

> He was killed.
>
> He was washed.

Note that the meaning of **himself** in the first sentence is somewhat different: in this case, the reflexive pronoun really means **by himself** or **unaided** or **alone**. To make this passive mood without specifying the agent, you would have to say something like:

> It was done by one person.

Because **by himself** means alone, you cannot use **himself** as the agent without changing the meaning, for example:

> He was killed by himself - *what seems like the correct passive voice* sentence
>   He was alone when he was killed - *what it actually means*

Comment: What about: "**It was done by him personally**"? And "**The killing of himself was done by him personally**" and "**Washing himself was his personal doing**" or something like that?

Comment: @SovereignSun, **personally** means "done by the specified person **and not by anybody else**".  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/personally. This very specific meaning is appropriate for the first of your examples but not for the other two: furthermore, you can't really use **himself** in the second and third examples, because **himself** normally refers to the subject, and the subject in both of these sentences is a gerund- an action.

Comment: An ungraceful way of expressing it is "He was killed by his own self" but this is clumsy/slangey sounding and should be avoided where educated or formal speech is expected.

Comment: *By himself* does not always mean *alone*. Sometimes it's a reflexive construction. For example: *The Life of the Late Dr. Benjamin Franklin, as Written by Himself*. (Written before he died, published afterwards.) Context usually makes the meaning clear. For example, it seems unlikely that somebody would write *he was killed by himself* instead of *he killed himself*, so in that case one would assume that it meant *alone*.